# I want to replace one fragment with another but these should happen based on button clicked in some other fragment(main one)

Tags: android

[Front end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MWbq.jpg)I have three fragment one will be the main fragment and the other two fragments for some tasks, I want to display the remaining fragment by clicking the buttons in main fragment but the main fragment should not be replaced so that if I click the other button the previous one should be replaced by the the new button , this should continue based on the buttons I click

```
enter code here
```

MainActivity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
        <fragment
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/headline_fragment"
            android:name="com.example.fragments.headlinefragment"
            android:layout_weight="1"></fragment>
        <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/baseline"
        android:name="com.example.fragments.baseline"
            android:layout_weight="1"></fragment>
</LinearLayout>

fragment1.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="headline" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

- similarly for other two

fragment.java:
    package com.example.fragments;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class headlinefragment extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.headline_fragment,container,false);
        return view;

    }
}
```

-similar for other two

Comment: I think you will get better responses if your question was accompanied by some code as to what you have done so far and what you exactly need help with

Comment: Please draw a picture of the UI that you want to implement. We call this storyboarding and is a very useful tool to communicate your design ideas.

Comment: I don't know how to reply for specific comment I took both ur advice nd I'm wrking in it, is the image I post on the starting is enough for u Code-Apprentice?

Answer (score 0):

ok this isnt a great solution, but you can just show or hide the view using set visibility, the actual way to do this is to inflate your fragment using a tag and then check if its in the layout has been added etc before deciding whether to show or remove it, but if your only showing a small fragment that doesnt do much you can include it in your layout like you have already except inside a frame layout and then call fragmentHolder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); or View.INVISIBLE to toggle it on and off